# getting docker-compose error in running microservices containers

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

I have created a saperate folder and put docker-compose.yml file .Then use 
yo jhipster:docker-compose and answer all the questions but after this question -

Which applications do you want to include in your configuration?

when I select the gateway of my apps .I am getting this error----

TypeError: Cannot read property 'generator-jhipster' of undefined
    at appsFolders.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/docker-prompts.js:177:36)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at prompt.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/docker-prompts.js:174:26)
    at

Pls suggest if anyone got this error in configuring docker-compose file.

Comment: Did you run it in a folder that contains applications as sub folders?

Comment: I am using saperate folder to run yml file.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You should edit your question with details about project folders if you want any help.